# How to find the operator $A$ in the second order correction to the ground state energy of Hydrogen (Stark effect)

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Consider that the hydrogen atom is placed in a constant electric field $F$ along the negative $z$-direction.

Hamiltonian $$H=H_0+H_1$$where $$H_0=-\frac{1}{2}\bigtriangledown^2-\frac{1}{r}\qquad,\qquad H_1=-Fr\cos\theta\qquad (\text{in a.u.})$$ $H_0~$ is the unperturbed Hamiltonian and $~H_1~$ is a small perturbation.

The second order correction to the ground state energy of Hydrogen is given by
$$E^{(2)}_{1s}=\sum_{m, ~(m~\ne ~n)}\frac{|\langle\phi_m^{(0)}|H_1|\phi_n^{(0)}\rangle|^2}{E_n^{(0)}-E_m^{(0)}}\tag1$$

Let there exists an operator $~A~$ such that $$H_1|\phi_n^{(0)}\rangle=(AH_0-H_0A)|\phi_n^{(0)}\rangle\tag2$$

Using $(2)$, from $(1)$ we have $$E^{(2)}_{1s}=\langle\phi_n^{(0)}|H_1A|\phi_n^{(0)}\rangle\tag3$$

Thus we see that determination of the second order correction depends on finding the operator $~A~$ defined by equation $(2)$. **It can be shown that the operator $~A~$ depends on the coordinates only, and, in spheriacal polar coordinates, it is given by $$A=-F\left(\frac{r}{2}+1\right)r\cos \theta$$**

From here my problem starts. I  have no idea **how to find this operator $~A~$**.

Can any one provide me the full calculation in simple language ?

Thank you in advance.

---

**Edit:**  If you have another way to find  the **second order correction to the ground state energy of Hydrogen (Stark effect)**, then you are also welcome. But please give the full explanation about each and every step.

Comment: There’s no point in showing my work now. Your key confusion, I believe, was in not understanding that the solution for $A$ was only valid for the ground state. And, as I stated, you had a sign mistake, so the proof you were asking for was impossible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97888/discussion-on-question-by-nmasanta-how-to-find-the-operator-a-in-the-second-or).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use the convention for the wavefunction of the hydrogen atom as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Wavefunction). We're interested in the second-order correction to the energy of the ground state due to an electric field. In appropriate units the ground state Hamiltonian is $H_0 = -\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2 -\frac{1}{r}$. If we add an electric field in the $z$ direction, the Hamiltonian becomes $H=H_0+H_1$ with $H_1 = Fr\cos{\theta}$. One can choose $F$ positive or negative depending on whether the field is in the positive or negative $z$ direction. The sign choice we make differs from OP's unnumbered equation so that in the end we get $A$ as in the OP's question; if we chose $H_1$ as in the OP's question, then the sign in $A$ would be flipped. I will follow Aruldhas section 9.5.

We're interested in the shift in the ground state, that is the $n=1, l=0$ (and therefore $m=0$) state of the hydrogen atom. We write $\phi^{(0)}_n$ for the $n$-th $l=0$ eigenstate of $H_0$. By direct computation, the first order energy shift vanishes. The second order energy shift is given by
$$E^{(2)}_{1}=\sum_{m, m\neq 1}\frac{|\langle\phi_m^{(0)}|H_1|\phi_1^{(0)}\rangle|^2}{E_1^{(0)}-E_m^{(0)}}$$
This should be compared with OP's eq. $(1)$. However this can be written in a different form which can be more suited to our uses. The first order correction to the ground state wavefunction is
$$\phi^{(1)}_1= \sum_{m, m\neq 1}\frac{\langle\phi_m^{(0)}|H_1|\phi_1^{(0)}\rangle}{E_1^{(0)}-E_m^{(0)}}\phi_m^{(0)}$$
so that the corrected wavefunction (to first order) would be $\phi^{(0)}_1+\phi^{(1)}_1$. Therefore one can also write the second order energy shift as
$$E^{(2)}_{1}=\langle\phi_1^{(0)}|H_1|\phi_1^{(1)}\rangle$$
This formula is not very useful as it is. But now suppose that we could find an operator $A$ such that
$$A|\phi_1^{(0)}\rangle = |\phi_1^{(1)}\rangle$$
Then we get $E^{(2)}_{1}=\langle\phi_1^{(0)}|H_1 A|\phi_1^{(0)}\rangle$, which is substantially simpler than evaluating the full infinite sum, at least if $A$ is simple enough. To determine $A$ we can't simply use its definition, because we would need to compute $\phi_1^{(1)}$ and that's as bad as computing the infinite sum. So we take a different route. The eigenvalue equation $H \phi = E \phi$ can be written to first order (not zeroth order) as
$$H_1\phi_1^{(0)} +H_0\phi_1^{(1)} =E_1^{(1)} \phi_1^{(0)} +E_1^{(0)}\phi_1^{(1)}$$
But the first order energy shift $E_1^{(1)}$ vanishes, so using $A$ and $H_0$ we get 
$$(AH_0-H_0A)\phi_1^{(0)} = H_1\phi_1^{(0)}\tag{2'}$$
This should be compared with OP's eq. $(2)$, the main difference being that the relation must only be satisfied for the $n=1$ state (and in fact, as stated, OP's eq. $(2)$ is not true for $n\neq 1$). Note that if $A$ is a solution of $(2')$ and $B$ is any operator which commutes with the hamiltonian, then $A+B$ will also be a solution of $(2')$. Now as a simplifying assumption, suppose that $A$ is a scalar function (i.e. it contains no derivatives). After all, we don't care about a specific solution, any solution will do. Since $A$ is a scalar, it commutes with the $1/r$ part of $H_0$. So expanding $(2')$ using the chain rule we get
$$\phi_1^{(0)}\nabla^2 A +2 \nabla A \cdot \nabla \phi_1^{(0)}=2H_1 \phi_1^{(0)}$$
In OP's choice of units and with the Wikipedia convention, $\phi_1^{(0)} = C e^{-r/n}$ where $C$ is some constant. So in fact we get
$$\nabla^2 A - 2\frac{\partial A}{\partial r}=2H_1$$
As for how to solve this, it is usually very hard to solve PDEs and in many cases most of it is guesswork. The only $\theta$ dependence in $H_1$ is through $\cos{\theta}$ which is equal to $P_1(\cos{\theta})$, where $P_1$ is a Legendre polynomial. These are eigenfunctions of the laplacian, so we can guess $A = B(r) \cos{\theta}$ and in fact the $\theta$ dependence vanishes, and we get
$$\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial B}{\partial r}\right)-2\frac{1}{r^2}B-2\frac{\partial B}{\partial r}=2Fr$$
or expanding
$$\frac{\partial^2 B}{\partial r^2}+2\left(\frac{1}{r}-1\right)\frac{\partial B}{\partial r}-2\frac{1}{r^2}B=2Fr$$
which is an equation for $B$ only. We can then look for a series solution $B(r)=F \sum_l a_l r^l$, which gives $A$ as in the OP's question. Alternatively, we see that the coefficients of the equation are singular at $r=0$. Therefore expanding for small $r$ we get the equation
$$\frac{\partial^2 B}{\partial r^2}+2\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial B}{\partial r}-2\frac{1}{r^2}B=0$$
This is an equidimensional equation which has a solution of the form $r^k$. Substituting and solving the quadratic we get $k=1$ or $k=-2$. We choose $k=1$, which is non singular, so in fact $B\approx r$ near zero. It is therefore useful to write $B(r) = r F G(r)$ (we put in $F$ to get rid of it). Substituting we get a simpler equation
$$\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial r^2}+(4-2r)\frac{\partial G}{\partial r}-2G=2r$$
This you can [plug into WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%2B%284-2x%29y%27-2y%20%3D%202x).They give the solution in a complicated form, but some things cancel out and you can choose the constants to get rid of the nasty part, getting the particular solution $G = -(r/2+1)$.

Comment: You were faster ಥ_ಥ

Comment: @Olexot I know the feeling! :)

Comment: Very thorough explanation! By the way, it seems there is no sign mistake. If you choose the field along the z-axis, which means that you choose $H_1=-Fr\cos\theta$, you'll obtain minus sign in $A$ operator. If you choose the opposite field direction as you did, there will be plus sign

Comment: I consider "$~F~$ along the negative z-direction", so I wrote $~H_1=-Fr\cos\theta~$.

Comment: @Olexot That's right! Thanks :)

Comment: @nmasanta, if I'm not mistaken, it means that you consider $F$ along the positive $z$-direction. If you work in classical mechanics, the potential $U=-Fz$ gives you $F_z=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial z}=F$

Comment: @nmasanta Ah missed that, sorry! You're perfectly free to do that, but then you would also have to flip the sign in $A$

Comment: @nmasanta I've edited the answer to change this

Comment: Thanks for your time. @John Donne ~ Let me give some time to cross check the whole matter. Again thank you vary much.

Comment: @Olexot I checked the calculation again and I think the sign does need to be flipped. If you look at $(2')$, it's clear that if you flip the sign of $H_1$ you'll also need to flip the sign of $A$. So we disagree on whether a $+$ or a $-$ in $H_1$ will give rise to a $-$ in $A$. As a check that it's the $+$ that gives rise to the $-$, Aruldhas gets the same sign as in this answer. Moreover, the correction needs to be negative (as is clear from the second order energy shift formula), so $A$ and $H_1$ must have opposite sign

Comment: In one of the previous comment I said that there is no sign mistake. But I also made a mistake and worked with $H_1=Fr\cos\theta$. So, if you choose **positive** direction ($H_1=-Fr\cos\theta$), you'll obtain **plus** sign in $A$. And if you choose **negative** direction ($H_1=+Fr\cos\theta$), there will be **minus** sign in $A$. JohnDonne is right

Comment: Yes, he is. I pointed out that sign mistake in a comment a few hours before the answer was posted. The comment was moved to chat by a moderator. I also mentioned that the solution was only valid for the ground state, and that the most general solution has a singular part. I’m glad that John wrote a very nice answer, which I have upvoted, and he deserves the bounty.